# Git pull ignore image files

Tags: git

I'm a contributor on a repository that occasionally has images posted to it. The images are really not essential, but the other contributors will continue to `add` and `push` them to the repository. I would like to perform `pull` operations that ignore image file suffixes, such as `*.png`. The git directory is just taking up too much space, and I really don't need to be pulling these image files.

How can I not `pull` the image files, but get *everything* else?

Comment: That's not possible. Perhaps the image files can be extracted to a separate repository (perhaps made available through a submodule) that you can choose to not fetch from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sparse-checkout` to sparsly populate your working directory. `sparse-checkout` makes use of the [`skip-worktree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit) bit which makes git assume that the file in your working tree is up to date no matter what.

---

*For the following I'll assume that you are currently in the root of your repository and have a clean working tree (`git stash` e.g.).*

First you have to enable `sparse-checkout` using `git config core.sparsecheckout true`; after this you can define all patterns you want to "ignore" on checkout in `.git/info/sparse-checkout`.
The syntax is the same as in a `.gitignore` file, the difference being that you define all files you **want to checkout** not the ones you want to ignore.

Let's assume you want to avoid checking out all `png` files in your repository, then your `sparse-checkout` file could look like this:

```
*         # Include everything
!*.png    # Flag png files with the 'skip-worktree' bit
```

If you want to apply the `sparse-checkout` to your current working directory you have to execute a [`read-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html) command afterwards.

```
git read-tree -m -u HEAD
```

After that you can continue working with your repository as usual, without the "ignored" files in your working tree.

---

**TL;DR:**

- Activate `sparse-checkout`: `git config core.sparsecheckout true`
- Define a `sparse-checkout` file under `.git/info/` containing the patterns of files you want to **include**
- Update your working tree `git read-tree -m -u HEAD`

---

You can read more on `sparse-checkout` in the official documentation of [`git read-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout).